# In need of crime database for application

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, postgresql

I'm not sure if this is the right stackexchange site to post on, but I've been searching for crime data.  I don't care what format it is in, all I need is a crime associated to perhaps a latitude/longitude, area/neighborhood, or shape files.

Anyone know of any data sources for this?

Comment: Check with your local statistics office?

Comment: I'd expect someone over on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ to know where to find that. Seems to be on-topic there, too.

Comment: I tried to vote to close and migrate this to stats.stackexchange.com, but that wasn't one of the options. So I didn't vote to close. I gave an answer instead.

Comment: @Catcall, if you think a post should be moved to a site that's not among the options, flag the post for moderator attention and say that you think it should be moved there.

Comment: Thanks, svick. Had daughter; didn't have time.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a Google search.

Looking at a few results, a good US database seems to be [**National Archive of Criminal Justice Data**](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/NACJD/), or the [**Uniform Crime Reports by County**](http://fisher.lib.virginia.edu/collections/stats/crime/).

At any rate, [`GIS crime database`](http://www.google.com/search?q=gis%20crime%20database) has a lot of results.